# How to display image read from json file in react js?

Tags: reactjs

How do I display an image read from a json file?

This is my json file (brand1.js):

```
let brand1 = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Herringbone",
    "path": './assets/imgs/brand1/34-SAU028A.jpg'
}
]
export default brand1
```

I am importing the json file in my App.json file

```
import brand1 from './assets/json/brand1';

function App() {

<div>
        {
            brand1.map((item, i) => 
            <div key={i}>
              <img src={item.path} />
            </div>
           )
        }
</div>
```

But the image is not getting displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you look at the rendered html, does the `src` match what you expect? Is there an image at that location?

Comment: when I inspect it shows <img src="./assets/imgs/brand1/34-SAU028A.jpg">

Comment: because your path starts with dot

Comment: yours image is located on the  client app or server ?  and i advice you to only put the image name on the json file or db then concat it the the url in src

Comment: does it work if you remove the period at the start, changing`'./assets/imgs/brand1/34-SAU028A.jpg'` to `'/assets/imgs/brand1/34-SAU028A.jpg'`?

Comment: No. It does not work if I remove the period